# Как удалить значение словаря в Python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

Нужно удалить значение словаря по ключу. Например:

```
systems = {'Solar': ['Mercury', 'Earth', 'Mars']}
```

Чтобы можно было удалить `Mars`, а осталось:

```
systems = {'Solar': ['Mercury', 'Earth']}
```

Мой код:

```
import pickle
 
def read_data(filename):
    ''' получаем словарь из файла
если файла нет возвращаем пустой словарь'''
    try:
        with open('data.pickle', 'rb') as f:
             return pickle.load(filename)
    except:
        return {}
 
def save_data(filename, data):
    ''' сохраняем словарь в файл'''
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
 
def check():
    system = input('enter ZS:  ')
    if system not in systems:
        print('система добавлена в базу')
    return system
    
 
def planet(system):
    ''' заполняем планеты заданной системы или добавляем новые'''
    x = int(input(f' количество планет для системы {system} >>:  '))
    return [input('введите: ') for _ in range(x)]
    
 
 
filename = 'systems.txt'
systems = read_data(filename)


def _delS():
    d=input('enter system: ')
    del systems[d]



def _delP():
    system=input('enter system: ')
    planet=input('enter planet: ')
    systems.popitem(system,planet)


while True:
    print('1-add system/planet\n2-print systems/planets\n3-delit system with planets\n4-delit planet\n')
    key=int(input('choose menu'))
    if key==1:
        system = check()
        systems.setdefault(system, []).append(planet(system))
        save_data(filename, systems)
    elif key==2:
        read_data(filename)
        print(systems)
    elif key==3:
        _delS()
    elif key==4:
        _delP()
```

Удалять должна функция `_delP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
systems={'Solar':['Mercury','Earth','Mars']}
system_del = 'Solar'
planet_del = 'Mars'
systems[system_del].remove(planet_del)
```